# Rocket.chat issue

Tags: linux, rocket.chat

I have problem with installin Rocket.Chat server on ElementaryOS.
I try to unpack tgz file, but getting error.

Listing:

```
sudo apt-get install npm curl graphicsmagick
curl -L http://rocket.chat/releases/latest/download/ -o rocket.chat.tgz
tar zxvf rocket.chat.tgz
```

And after last command I get this error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I try `file rocket.chat.tgz`:

```
rocket.chat.tgz: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Comment: apparently it is not a gzip file or is corrupted. could you send the output of these commands: `file rocket.chat.tgz` and `tar xvf rocket.chat.tgz` ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead use this url:

`curl -L https://releases.rocket.chat/latest/download -o rocket.chat.tgz`